# Detecting Retina picture to create a half sized image

Tags: javascript, image

When a user using a Retina display makes a screenshot and pastes it into the browser, the size of the image is twice the selected area. This is expected as a Retina display, but the pasted image should have the proper size (the same as the selection) and not double the size.

When doing a screenshot on MacOS, the OS adds some [Physical Pixel Dimensions](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter11.html#png.ch11.div.8)), called pHYs to the PNG image, which allows us to detect if they are in high definition.

Here's the code :

```javascript
const metersToInchMultiplies = 39.3701

// Retrieved from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37705109/330867
function stringAsUInt32BE (binString) {
    // Replace new DataView(Uint8Array.from(binString, c => c.charCodeAt(0)).buffer).getInt32(0, false)
    return binString.charCodeAt(0) * 16777216 + binString.charCodeAt(1) * 65536 + binString.charCodeAt(2) * 256 + binString.charCodeAt(3)
}

/**
 * This functions uses the pHYS property (http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter11.html#png.ch11.div.8)
 * of a given PNG file (often used in paste, mostly at Apple's) and identifies the pixels density
 *
 * If it is superior than 144, it considers that it is Retina, and provides the width and height as half.
 *
 * @param Sring imgBase64
 * @returns Object
 */
function getRetinaDimensions (imgBase64) {
    const imgBin = window.atob(imgBase64)

    // Thanks to https://gist.github.com/jorilallo/23282a4887ab8ef166182c1dab1677f0 for the help!
    const physPos = imgBin.indexOf('pHYs')
    if (physPos > -1) {
        const phys = imgBin.substring(physPos + 4, physPos + 4 + 9)
        if (phys.charCodeAt(8) === 1) {
            // Unit is in metter, as expected!
            const xPpm = stringAsUInt32BE(phys.substring(0, 4))
            const xDpi = Math.round(xPpm / metersToInchMultiplies)

            const yPpm = stringAsUInt32BE(phys.substring(4, 8))
            const yDpi = Math.round(yPpm / metersToInchMultiplies)

            if (xDpi >= 144 && yDpi >= 144) {
                const ihdrPos = imgBin.substring(0, 30).indexOf('IHDR')
                if (ihdrPos > -1) {
                    const ihdr = imgBin.substring(ihdrPos + 4, ihdrPos + 4 + 8)
                    Uint8Array.from(ihdr, c => c.charCodeAt(0))
                    const width = stringAsUInt32BE(ihdr.substring(0, 4))
                    const height = stringAsUInt32BE(ihdr.substring(4, 8))
                    return {
                        width: Math.round(width / 2),
                        height: Math.round(height / 2)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null
}

window.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
    const hasFiles =
        event.clipboardData &&
        event.clipboardData.files &&
        event.clipboardData.files.length

    if (!hasFiles) return

    const images = Array.from(event.clipboardData.files).filter(file => /image/i.test(file.type))
    if (images.length === 0) return

    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopImmediatePropagation()

    images.forEach(image => {
        const reader = new FileReader()

        reader.onload = readerEvent => {
            const img = new Image()
            img.src = readerEvent.target.result

            if (isRetina) {
                const dimensions = getRetinaDimensions(img.src.substring(options.src.indexOf(',') + 1))
                if (dimensions) {
                    img.width = dimensions.width
                    img.height = dimensions.height
                }
            }

            // Add that image anywhere you want.
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(image)
    })
}
```

The `getRetinaDimensions` tries to retrieve the `pHYs` details and tests if the data is in high definition. If that's the case, it returns an Object containing the new Width and Height divided by two. Otherwise, nothing is returned.

*The reason nothing is returned is to let the browser handle the size in that case.*